# No se puede validar porque C/wamp64/bin/php74.33/php.exe no es un ejecutable PHP válido

Tags: php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas compañeros, no puedo resolver este problema y ya copie la ruta pero no se arregla.

Comment: En `Windows` el `path` debería ser algo como: `C:\wamp64\bin\php\phpX.Y.Z`

Comment: asi mismo le puse pero igual me da error

Comment: Eso te da al iniciar WAMP? Puedes poner una captura total del error, quizás veamos algo que nos de mas pistas.

Comment: Cuendo abro visual estudio code en la esquina inferior derecha me sale el mensaje adjunto mas arriba el mensaje de error

Comment: es el plugin de php que quiere validar el código usando una instalacion de php. no es critico, puede ignorarse. al editar las preferencias fijate que puede que necesites escapear las \ https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jtM7.png

Comment: Ya encontre el problema, en wamp64 estaba corriendo php version 8.0.26 y yo estaba apuntando la ruta de la carpeta a la otra version de php en este caso la 7.4.33

Comment: ya encontre el problema la ruta donde esta alojado el php.exe era el incorrecto, mi wamp64 estaba usando php 8.0.26 y yo estaba apuntando a la version 7 de php

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque el OP ha indicado que el problema se debía a que se equivoco al buscar la ruta del `php.exe`